# How to select specific content from table type structure in html

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

HTML structure I am working on is:

```
<tr showhide="show" style="display: table-row; ">
            <td class="monthlyCost">£18<span>.50</span></td>
                      <td class="phoneCost">£299.99</td>
                      <td><span class="lowLight">24 Months</span></td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>Unlimited</td>
            <td class="dataAllowance">100MB</td>
            <td class="extras">
```

I am using following Python code to extract information:

```
minutes       = tariff_link_soup.findAll('td', {"class": False})
texts         = tariff_link_soup.findAll('td', {"class": False})
```

**Problem:** I want information mentioned in these two `td` (`<td>200</td>` & `<td>Unlimited</td>`) tags in 2 different columns minutes & texts. But my method which defines class as false, finds 3 arguments `24 Months` , `200` & `Unlimited`continually.

I understand the problem but not able to devise a solution for it. There are 2 parts to it, first I don't want data in `lowlight` class , second I want data in next two `td` tags to be in 2 different columns, I can the separate the two in 2 columns even if I can get them together like `200 Unlimited`

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using BeautifulSoup 3, the correct call would be:

```
.findAll('td', {'class': None})
```

That gives me:

```
>>> results = s.findAll('td', {'class': None})
>>> results
[<td><span class="lowLight">24 Months</span></td>, <td>200</td>, <td>Unlimited</td>]
```

As you're calling this twice, you will get the same data in both `minutes` and `texts`. I assume your table's columns are not going to change, so you'd have to use indexing:

```
>>> minutes = results[1]
>>> texts = results[2]
>>> minutes, texts
(<td>200</td>, <td>Unlimited</td>)
```